# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Requests_Hooks' not found when use Request

Tags: php, httprequest

When I use [Requests](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests)

in my smarty's `test.php` file:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/libs/src/Requests/library/Requests.php');

$headers = array('Accept'=>'application/json', 'Authorization' => 'Bearer AwSBtNOd3Fw4NkDUDdoZqqwFOCKDxi');
$request = Requests::get('http://localhost:8000/amodel/list/', $headers, []);

$res = array(
    'status'=>var_dump($request->status_code),
    'data'=>var_dump($request->body)
);

$smarty->assign('res', $res);

$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

but when I access the `test.php`, there I get Fatal Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Requests_Hooks' not found in /Users/james/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/libs/src/Requests/library/Requests.php:568 Stack trace: #0 /Users/james/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/libs/src/Requests/library/Requests.php(363): Requests::set_defaults('http://localhos...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array) #1 /Users/james/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/libs/src/Requests/library/Requests.php(231): Requests::request('http://localhos...', Array, NULL, 'GET', Array) #2 /Users/james/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/test.php(36): Requests::get('http://localhos...', Array, Array) #3 {main} thrown in /Users/james/Desktop/TestPHP/smarty-test02/libs/src/Requests/library/Requests.php on line 568

---

**EDIT-1**

I was follow the GitHub docs, I am not sure where is the reason evocable this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library, like most modern PHP libraries, depends on autoloading. If you're using composer, you get that for free. If you're manually installing it, you need to take care of the autoloader. As the documentation states:

> And include it in your scripts:
>
> ```
> require_once '/path/to/Requests/library/Requests.php';
> ```
>
> You'll probably also want to register an autoloader:
>
> ```
> Requests::register_autoloader();
> ```